# How to interpret RFC3339 UTC timestamp

Tags: time, timestamp, utc, rfc3339

How should I interpret all aspects of the following timestamps?  Where is the time based and how do timezones apply?

```
2015-11-15T14:45:28Z
2015-11-15T14:45:28.9694Z
2015-11-15T14:45:28.969412345Z
```

Below is my thoughts...

```
Date:    2015-11-15
???:     T
Hours:   14
Minutes: 45
Seconds: 28 OR 28.9694 OR 28.969412345
???:     Z
```

Comment: T is just there for formatting, like the - and : in the date and time. As for timezones: Z always refers to UTC.

Comment: @Rhymoid  Ah, so no time zone, just the time at 0° longitude, right?

Comment: Yes, except without any daylight saving nonsense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of your values are attributed correctly. The date portion (`2015-11-15`) is in the order `YYYY-MM-DD`, time in `HH:MM:SS.ffff`.

`T` indicates the start of the time portion of the date time.

`Z` indicates the time zone is UTC. Next to `Z`, you could have a format like `Z+02:00`, which indicates the time zone is UTC + 2 hours.